# How would I use [index: number] : string defined in a TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading a book about a frontend library, [Angular UI Development with PrimeNG](https://www.packtpub.com/product/angular-ui-development-with-primeng/9781788299572). The author is brushing up TypeScript. He touches in a TypeScript feature but doesn't give it an example.

> Typescript allows you to use the syntax `[index: type]` to specify a
> `string` or `number` type based collection of key/value pairs.
> Interfaces perfectly fit such data structures. For example, consider
> the following syntax:
>
> ```
> interface Dictionary {
>    [index: number]: string
> }
> ```

How would I use this in a real example?

Comment: That is not good writing, it feels like there's a whole following paragraph missing. These are _index signatures_, start with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures.

Comment: To explain another way, the example type is equivalent to `Record<number, string>`, but index signatures have many additional uses, such as [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) etc.

Comment: It really feels like *for sure* there must be an existing SO question that explains this directly, but I haven't been able to find one that doesn't already start from kinda sorta knowing what index signatures are.  

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WvE7km) make sense and seem like a "real" example to you? (Note that I changed your `Dictionary` to `NumkeyDict` because usually a "dictionary" has arbitrary string keys.  Usually numeric index signatures like `{[index: number]: string}` are used for array-like things, not dictionary-like things.)  If so I can write up an answer about it.  If not, what am I missing?